# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem : randomly time gain... or huge loss

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I use a quite time consuming process (~1ms) in a loop (~100000 calls), with different but not interdependent input values. This is the perfect configuration for multithreading!

I handle multithreading with: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, and I keep track of how many items are in the queue so there is never more than 6 tasks waiting to get called (thus 4+6 tasks, as I have 4 processor threads)

The behavior is really strange. When I run the same code (but possibly different compilations or different data, though no difference that is likely to make much of a difference), either:
- The windows task manager tells me that all 4 threads are almost saturated, the program is 2-3 times faster than the single thread program
- The windows task manager shows little use of any processor, and the program is vastly slower than the single thread version.

I use VS2015, and use .NET framework 4.6.1

Has anyone seen such a weird behavior? Is there a way to avoid such time loss?

```
Sub TaskMulti()
    Dim threadlist(0 To  System.Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 + 2 - 1) as integer
    Dim ith as integer
    For ith  = 0 To UBound(threadlist)
        threadFinished(ith) = True
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(AllTasks)
       replay:
            For ith = 0 To UBound(threadlist)
                If threadFinished(ith) Then
                    threadFinished(ith) = False
                    threadlist(ith) = i
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf TaskDoSimple, ith)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If ith > UBound(threadlist) Then
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
                GoTo replay
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

replay2:

```
    For ith = 0 To UBound(threadlist)
        If Not threadFinished(ith) Then
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
            GoTo replay2
        End If
    Next
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
End Sub
Sub TaskDoSimple(i as integer)
    'do the job knowing the job ID is  threadlist(ith)
End Sub
```

Comment: The behaviour is expected. If you create a random large number of threads, you may get far worse performance than if you created a limited number. If you create more CPU-bound jobs than cores, you'll get worse performance for example. If you create a lot of IO bound jobs, you may or may not get worse performance, but you'll waste CPU.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why aren't you using TPL's methods? Why aren't you using `Task.Run` for example, or PLINQ ? Why are you trying to manage the number of *jobs* (you don't have threads, only jobs here) instead of letting the threadpool handle this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I am aware that creating vast numbers of threads is bad, that's why I limit the queue to 6 threads: not enough to cause such problems. The reason is that I would rather be compatible with older VB.NET frameworks, which do not include task objects. I'll have a look though.

Comment: If you want to process a large list in parallel, use `Parallel.For/ForEach`. This will partition the data into as many partitions as there are cores, and use one task for each partition, ensuring you use all cores. *Your code* doesn't have to do anything, TPL takes care of partitioning and calculating the optimal size. You could also use PLINQ, with the same effects

Comment: there are no supported .NET frameworks that don't have Tasks. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2 Tasks were introduced in 4.0, 7 years ago. You'll be hard-pressed to find a machine without 4.0 at least. Especially *now*, that everyone is switching to TLS 1.2, available in 4.5.2

Comment: If you are, by any chance, targeting an older NET Framework version then you can use the TaskParallelLibrary Nuget package which is a backport if NET 4's TPL implementation.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : wow the Parallel.for is truely the way to go! That's simple to use! Well I'll use that & if need be that it should work on older frameworks, it'll be in single core and I'm done with it :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you kindly add this as an answer so I can mark it as "answered" instead of deleting it? This might help others.